# $rootScope:infdig error in angularjs 1.4.0

Tags: angularjs

I have the following markup in a form mixed with some asp.net razor:

```
<div class="account-form__field-container" ng-show="postcodeRequired()" ng-cloak>
    @Html.LabelFor(x => x.Postcode)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Postcode, new { @class = "account-form__field", placeholder = "Postcode here...", ng_required = "postcodeRequired()",ng_validpostcode="", ng_model = "postcode", ng_init = "postcode = '" + Model.Postcode + "'" })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.Postcode, null, new { @class = "account-form__error-message" })
    <span class="account-form__error-message" ng-show="registrationForm.$submitted && registrationForm.Postcode.$error.required" ng-cloak>
        Please enter your postcode
    </span>
    <span class="account-form__error-message" ng-show="registrationForm.$submitted && !validPostCode()" ng-cloak>
        Please enter valid postcode
    </span>
</div>
```

I have a dropdown which will show hide the postcode field, so if uk selected the postcode field will show.  The field is required but additionally I am doing a check in whether is a valid postcode via a webservice.  The angular controller that deals with form submission looks like:

```
        $scope.submitForm = function () {

        $scope.registrationForm.$submitted = true;

        if ($scope.enableSubmit()) {
            registrationForm.submit();
        }
    };

    $scope.postcodeRequired = function () {
        return $scope.country === 'United Kingdom';
    };

    $scope.validPostCode = function () {
        if ($scope.postcodeRequired()) {
            if ($scope.postcode !== undefined && $scope.postcode.length > 5) {
                postcodeService.ValidatePostCode($scope.postcode).success(function (response) {
                    return response;
                });

            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    };

     $scope.enableSubmit = function () {
        return $scope.registrationForm.$valid
            && $scope.passwordsMatch()
            && $scope.acceptTerms
            && $scope.validPostCode();
    };
```

The postCodeService is just doing an http get to validate the post code that returns true or false.  The issue i have is on submitting it validates the postcode but then goes into a loop and gives the following error:

```
angular.min.js:34 Uncaught Error: [$rootScope:infdig] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.0/$rootScope/infdig?p0=10&p1=%5B%5D
at angular.min.js:34
at m.$digest (angular.min.js:563)
at m.$apply (angular.min.js:571)
at l (angular.min.js:373)
at O (angular.min.js:388)
at XMLHttpRequest.N.onload (angular.min.js:392)
```

I have seen other people with this issue when doing an ng-repeat but as you can see I am not doing that.

Any ideas?

Comment: In your `validPostCode` function, if the two `if` statements evaluate to true and call `postcodeService.ValidatePostCode(...)`, because that is an asynchronous function (calls the server and returns a promise) the code continues to run after that.  Thus any time it need to validate the postcode from the server, it will always hit the `return true` line at the end of the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without a plunkr to test against and verify its hard to tell exactly what is causing the infinite digest cycle loop.   However I believe it might be cause by the amount of calls made towards your `$scope.validPostCode` function (which wasn't correctly returning its validity).  Basically the change proposed is to only call the validate function when the postcode has been changed (trigged by `ng-change` on the field).  The result of that function sets `$scope.validPostCode` variable to true or false, which is then what is checked for validity;

**HTML** (add `ng-change` to the input)

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Postcode, new { <!-- other attributes -->, ng_change = "validatePostCode()" })
```

**JavaScript**

```
$scope.postcodeRequired = function () {
    return $scope.country === 'United Kingdom';
};

// by default its not valid
$scope.validPostCode = false;

// our Validition check
$scope.validatePostCode = function () {
    if ($scope.postcodeRequired()) {
        if ($scope.postcode !== undefined && $scope.postcode.length > 5) {
            postcodeService.ValidatePostCode($scope.postcode).success(function (response) {
                $scope.validPostCode = response;
            });
        } else {
            $scope.validPostCode = false;
        }
    } else {
        $scope.validPostCode = true;
    }
};

// call our function to properly set the initial validity state.
$scope.validatePostCode();

$scope.enableSubmit = function () {
    return $scope.registrationForm.$valid
        && $scope.passwordsMatch()
        && $scope.acceptTerms
        && $scope.validPostCode;
};
```

Comment: So had to make a couple of tweaks but your solution put me on the right track

Comment: Awesome.  Glad it helped.